# How to fix Unable to find Gradle tasks to build in finished Project

Tags: android-studio

Here logs
`Deprecated Gradle features were used in this build, making it incompatible with Gradle 8.0.

You can use '--warning-mode all' to show the individual deprecation warnings and determine if they come from your own scripts or plugins.

See https://docs.gradle.org/7.4/userguide/command_line_interface.html#sec:command_line_warnings

BUILD SUCCESSFUL in 2m 28s
`
[image: Finished Project]

I try many change to plugins but give me error
now project is finished, but the error has not gone away